# How to design SQL schema for query which returns different types of data

Tags: sql, database-design

We have an application in which we need to return many results, and each result can be associated with many different properties and these properties can be complex.

To explain the problem, let me describe one possible design for meeting the requirement.

A. Create a table which contains columns which are foreign keys to the complex properties.

```
CREATE TABLE Results
(
  Id int NOT NULL,
  UserId int NULL,
  DataForTable1Id int NULL,
  DataForTable2Id int NULL,
  DataForTable3Id int NULL,
  DataForTable4Id int NULL,
  DataForTable5Id int NULL,
  DataForTable6Id int NULL,
  DataForTable7Id int NULL,
  DataForTable8Id int NULL,
  DataForTable9Id int NULL
)
```

B. Additionally, each complex property may also be associated with other complex properties.  For example, DataForTable1 might look like:

```
CREATE TABLE DataForTable1
(
    Id int NOT NULL,
    UserId1 int NULL,
    UserId2 int NULL,
)
```

C. Create a separate query for each of the complex properties, e.g.:

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
    Table1 t 
    JOIN Results r on t.Id = r.DataForTable1Id
    LEFT JOIN Users u1 on r.UserId1 = u1.Id
    LEFT JOIN Users u2 on r.UserId2 = u2.Id`
```

This will solve the problem, but requires executing a separate query for each complex property.  When there are lots of results, this will not perform ideally, especially as more and more complex properties are added.

Additionally, the tables DataForTable1, DataForTable2, etc. are tables which need to exist in the system outside of this requirement.  For example, these tables may represent Users or other objects which are apart of the application.

I am wondering if others are solving similar problems, and if so, how they are doing it.  It may be anything from: "here's how I would design my tables" to "stop using relational databases.  here's what you should be using...".

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Thanks,
Eric

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? In Postgres, `hstore` would seem like a good fit

Answer (score 1):

I would not use a RDMS for this. I would opt to use a graph database like Neo4j. Each property that you have in your system would be represented as nodes in the graph. And each association would be represented as edges in your graph database. You can then use the Cypher query language to get at any relationship/association in the database. Graph databases are ideally suited to represent these types of relationships/associations which are sometimes difficult to model in relational databases.